# Triangle program code

Tags: python

I was making a program the other day for printing a program with the following output:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

I was researching about this in the net when I found [this snippet of code](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.python/python-basics/2999398):

```
n=input('Enter a number')
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print str(i)*i
```

It produced the output I wanted, but however I could not understand the last line which said

```
str(i)*i
```

Why is it `str`? I see no string in the code? Please can anyone explain this to me? I don't want to write a code I don't understand.

Comment: Have you tried looking in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)? Trying it out in the interpreter?

Comment: @jinrsharpe yes i have believe it didnt work....thats why i came here...

Comment: What do you mean *"believe it didnt [sic] work"*?! What did you try, what happened and what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried messing with the code so that i didnt get the str problem since i didnt understand it but i could not get it rihght....I was not able to understand why he used str....so i posted the link as well...no need to get angry man...

Comment: What *"str problem"*? You should include what you've tried and describe what is wrong with it; that might help people pin down exactly what is confusing you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe as i said my friend, i could not understnad why he used str at the end of the code...i got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str()` converts the integer `i` to a string object. Multiplying a *string* as opposed to an integer produces a repeated string, while multiplying the integer would give you a different integer instead:

```
>>> i = 5
>>> 5 * 5
25
>>> str(5)
'5'
>>> str(5) * 5
'55555'
```

So `5 * 5` is `25`, but `'5' * 5` is `'55555'` instead.

Comment: why is everybody dislking my question?? i posted the source and enough of my research....im not making people spoonfeed me....im gonna get blocked...

Comment: @MadhavManohar: I didn't vote, but looking up the documentation and trying things out yourself should be part of your research. My answer shows you how you can try this out for yourself in an interactive interpreter, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In the code it uses `str` because if it was an integer it would be multiplied then printed like this:

```
>>> i = 4
>>> i * i
16
```

But if it's `str` it would print it `i` times:

```
>>> str(i) * i
'4444'
```

Comment: Not five times, 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

str() is just returning string object. So if you multiply to string it will repeat your string and for integer it will perform mathematical operation.

Comment: Python doesn't really have type casting. `str()` returns a new object, a string object, instead.